# CSS position off by 1px - why?

Tags: html, css

The topic says it all.

As long as my pc is on you can view the HTML on this adress: http://78.60.9.233:8080

Here a screenshot of the white 1px line.

http://s16.postimg.org/6gv1ebptg/SSS.jpg

Top element is set to 5% height 0% top position.
Middle element is set to 65% height 5% top position.
Bottom element is set to 30% height and 0% bottom.

Yet, there is a small space between the middle and bottoms elements.

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type='application/javascript' src='fastclick.js'></script>

 <script>

  $(function() {
   FastClick.attach(document.body);
  });

  $(function() {
   $('.tabs .navigation a').on('click', function(e)  {
    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

          // Show/Hide Tabs
          $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

          // Change/remove current tab to active
          $(this).parent('td').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

          e.preventDefault();
      });
  });

 </script>

 <style type="text/css">

  * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow-x:hidden;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -khtml-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
     -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
     -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari 3.0 - 5.0, Chrome 1 - 9, Android 2.1 - 3.x */
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox 1 - 28 */
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .tab {
   display:none;
  }

  .tab.active {
   display:block;
  }


  .navigation  {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0%;
     border-spacing: 0px;
     font-size: 0px;
     height: 30%;

     


  }


  .navigation td {
   border: 1px solid black;
   text-align:center;


  }

  td.active {
  background-color: #b0c4de;

  }

  .action-nav1 {
     border-spacing: 0px;
     width: 100%;


  }





  .top-icons td {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 100%;
   height: 5%;
   overflow: hidden;


  }

  .tab-content  {
   position: absolute;
   top: 5%;
   width: 100%;
   height: 65%;

  }

 

 </style>
</head> 

<body>





<table class="top-icons">

  <tr>

   <td><img src="photo.png" style="height:100%"><img src="photo.png" style="height:100%"><img src="photo.png" style="height:100%"><img src="photo.png" style="height:100%"><img src="photo.png" style="height:100%"></td>



  </tr>

 </table>

</div>

<div class="tabs">

 <table class="navigation">

  <tr>

   <td class="active"><a href="#tab1"><img src="photo.png" style="width:80%"></a></td>
   <td><a href="#tab2"><img src="photo.png" style="width:80%"></a></td>
   <td><a href="#tab3"><img src="photo.png" style="width:80%"></a></td>
   <td><a href="#tab4"><img src="photo.png" style="width:80%"></a></td>
   <td><a href="#tab5"><img src="photo.png" style="width:80%"></a></td>


  </tr>

 </table>

  <div class="tab-content">

   <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
    <table class="action-nav1">
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Labas</td>
    </tr>
   
    </table>
   </div>

   <div id="tab2" class="tab">
    <td>Tab #2 content goes here!</td>
   </div>

   <div id="tab3" class="tab">
    <td><p>Tab #3 content goes here!</p></td>
   </div>

   <div id="tab4" class="tab">
    <td><p>Tab #4 content goes here!</p></td>
   </div>

   <div id="tab5" class="tab">
    <td><p>Tab #5 content goes here!</p></td>
   </div>


  </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

What's wrong? How do I eliminate that 1px empty space?

Comment: Why are you including JQuery twice? And make a fiddle, we really don't want to look at your PC as we can't edit your code

Comment: Sorry, copy paste error :)

Comment: First thing to do is run the HTML through a validator so you can fix the errors.

Comment: Or rather in the snippet I selected jquery and it auto added that line.

Comment: Sorry I am new to HTML. By validator you mean something like http://validator.w3.org/? I just did, it did not give me any info how to solve my problem :(

Comment: Keep in mind, browsers make rounding errors.  They each have their own formulas for calculating CSS, and each of them makes unique rounding errors.  Try looking at it in other browsers to see how they render the page, and try resizing your browser window or changing the content - you may see the extra pixel come and go.  Also, try setting exact pixel distances and see if your mystery pixel vanishes.  Sometimes you have to accept a little margin of error when it comes to CSS and percentages.

Comment: it works fine on my FF 36.0.1, Chrome 41, IE 11. What browser shows the problem for you ? (and what OS)

Comment: Surreal, this html is for mobile, so I did check on android and iOS, the exact same thing. I noticed if I set the middle element to 65.1% instead of 65%, it displays perfectly on all the browsers including desktop and mobile. Is this good practise to leave it like that, even though I don't know how it works? :)

Comment: Gaby aka, I set it to 65.1 just now for testing, I'll set it back to 65%, please look at the problem again :)

Comment: If you haven't yet, I'd use some in-browser dev tools.  Identify the element where this is happening, and you should be able to see it's properties.  It looks fine for me (Chrome version is 40.0.2214.115)